# How to implement decoupled error handling in Golang?

Tags: go

Consider the following controller and repo.

```
var ErrNotFound = errors.New("not found")

type Resource struct {
   Name string
}

type repository interface {
   CreateResource(ctx context.Context, name string) (*Resource, error)
}

type Controller struct {
   Repo repository
}

func (c *Controller) CreateResource(ctx context.Context, name string) (*Resource, error) {
   r, err := c.Repo.CreateResource(ctx, name)
    
   // error checking ...
   if err != nil {
   }

   return r, nil
}
```

To keep things clean the controller also defines which protocol it expects any repo to adhere to. By the same token any sentinel errors should be defined by the controller rather than the repository. I can't really find any examples where errors are handled in this way which makes me question if this is indeed the correct approach. My questions is, what is the idiomatic way of decoupling error messages between different application layers?

Comment: [1/2] I don't quite parse your requirement: if a repo creates a resource, it's logical that it returns its own errors (the errors it knows about). A controller, which asked the repository to carry out a task, can "wrap" such an error into an error of its own type, if needed. Instead, if the key word in your question is "sentinel", then I posit that my 1st point still holds, and you either should use a common package (say, `resources`) which defines a set of errors or [assert behavior, not values](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/24/inspecting-errors)–basically errors adhering to your procotol…

Comment: [2/2] …should implement specific method (or a set of methods). Go uses duck typing when it comes to implementing interfaces, so there's no need to have an exported interface shared by multiple packages. I mean, errors reported by a repo may all have a method like `ResourceError() bool`, and the controller could have a private interface containing this method, against which it'd type-assert the errors.

Comment: the interface (Repository) is not used externally but as an interface which the repo has to match (duck typing I'm thinking), the mistake here was maybe to make it public. When it comes to a common package I don't follow you and for the asser behavior solution do you suggest that I add i.e. IsNotFound(err) to the Repository interface? Would be great if you could show me in code what you mean 

Comment: @ErikJohansson, you don't have to add to the repository interface. You can check if error values implement particular methods. For instance: `if err, ok := err.(interface{NotFound() bool}); ok && err.NotFound() { ... }`. For concrete examples, see [the error types in package net](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Error). They all have Timeout and Temporary methods. You can write package-level functions that do this assertion for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

you can define couple errs on each level
let's say repository can throw you ErrDB and ErrNotFound
you can check what error was actually returned to you and handle it like you want to.

```
r, err := c.Repo.CreateResource(ctx, name)
if errors.Is(err, repo.ErrNotFound) {
    //return 404
} else if errors.Is(err, repo.ErrDB ) {
    //return 500
}
```